# using sigaction and alarm to break from infinite loop

Tags: c++

This is my code :

```
#define _OPEN_SYS
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>


volatile int footprint = 0;

void catcher(int signum) {
puts("inside signal catcher!");
alarm(0);
footprint = 1;
return;
}

main() {
printf("footprint=%d\n", footprint);
struct sigaction sact;
sigemptyset(&sact.sa_mask);
sact.sa_flags = 0;
sact.sa_handler = catcher;
if (footprint == 0) {
    puts("the signal catcher never gained control");
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sact, NULL);
    printf("before loop");
    alarm(5); /* timer will pop in five seconds */
    while (true);
} else
    puts("the signal catcher gained control");
printf("after loop");
}
```

my output is :

```
footprint=0
the signal catcher never gained control
before loopinside signal catcher!
```

and the application keep running forever , I need someway to break this loop , I'm using similar code to make timeout for sybase statement execution as OCCI doesn't support timeout.

Comment: Maybe you mean while(footprint==0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals such as `SIGALRM` will interrupt most system calls (but beware of automatically restartable calls).  You cannot rely on them to interrupt your syscall-free loop.  And even when it does, execution resumes after a signal, so your code happily goes right back to looping.

In fact, your code is not even valid C++ (!!!). Section 1.10p24 of the Standard says:

> The implementation may assume that any thread will eventually do one
>   of the following:
>
> - terminate,
> - make a call to a library I/O function,
> - access or modify a volatile object, or
> - perform a synchronization operation or
>     an atomic operation.

Alex's suggestion of `while ( footprint == 0 ) ;` will at least correct this defect.

Comment: replace the infinite while loop with this pOracleConnStmt->executeUpdate();

Comment: @ahdy: That sounds like it should use at least a couple library I/O calls.  Do beware of restarted syscalls though, `executeUpdate` might happy go back to doing its thing and not return early despite the alarm signal (your handler will execute).

Comment: so i tried : OCIBreak((dvoid *)svchp,(OCIError *)errhp); in the catcher method but just as you said it totally ignores it.The only way to make it run is manually pressing ctrl+c in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

A loop such as `while (true);` can't be interrupted, except by terminating the thread executing it. The loop has to be coded to check for an interrupt condition and exit.

As Alex mentioned in a comment, `while ( footprint == 0 ) ;` would correctly implement a loop checking for the given signal handler.

Just being pedantic, `footprint` should be declared `sig_atomic_t` not `int`, but it probably doesn't matter.